# Getting page numbers in plain TeX

Tags: page-numbering, plain-tex

I know that TeX does not update the page number until it can decide where to break a page. And when I write

```
\number\count0

\number\count0

\number\count0
% ...
```

to fill two pages, the second page of the output begins with

```
1
1
2
2
2
...
```

Therefore, if something appears on the top of a page, then I can't get the correct page number for it. In LaTeX we have `\label` and `\pageref` as a workaround. But is there a way to do this in plain TeX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes of course you could implement the same system latex uses, with a two-pass writing to the aux file. You could define some macros just to do this or more simply

```
\input eplain
```

and use the eplain macros which provide various cross referencing features in a more plain style than the latex macros.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course you could implement the same system latex uses, with a two-pass writing to the auxiliary file. You could define some macros just to do this or more simply

```
\input opmac
```

and use the opmac macros `\ref` and `\pgref` which provide various cross referencing features in a more plain style than the latex macros.

Comment: This was cheap :(